# Google Maps shows wrong location on Android 2.2

Tags: google-maps, google-latitude

For the last two weeks, Google Maps (Latitude) reports that I'm still at my old house. I'm not - I moved 6 months ago, but my "location" says that I'm still there. I tried clearing the maps cache, manually setting my location to somewhere else, and then activating auto-detection. 
Still nothing.

What could go wrong?

Comment: Sign out from Google Latitude and Sign In again.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Latitude History is telling me that Im living on the next block](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/10427/google-latitude-history-is-telling-me-that-im-living-on-the-next-block)

Comment: Tried signing out & in, nothing changed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Settings > Applications > Manage Applications.

All > Network Location > Clear data.

Comment: Tried that, worked for about a minute, location changed back to the fake one...